# Simulate trusted user click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to dispatch event click event in Javascript, but it needs to be trusted by browser. `DispatchEvent` and `element.click()` trigger event, but `isTrusted` is false, so my handler can't perform all of desired actions. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `isTrusted`, as it's just read-only. A workaround is to find which part of the code provided uses it and simply remove the if statement or any logic that checks this property.

Comment: I don't check this property, but window.open does.

Comment: @VasilyiTarkovsky Could you please provide a short code snippet  in your question? Without it I cannot solve your question properly my way :)

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

According to the docs, it is not possible to change the value of `isTrusted`.

There is a not-so-great workaround if you are trying to automate some actions though... Write a program/script in another language to simulate the mouse click *(just so that the event is not dispatched by your program and is considered as trusted)* and run that script.

For example, you can use [Pynput - python library](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) to click on the coordinates passed to the program and use node.js to run the script locally.

Whenever you want to click the target element, get the coordinates of that element using js and pass it to the python script as args !

You can refer [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/run-python-script-from-node-js-and-send-data-to-browser-15677fcf199f) to run python script from js and [this pynput tutorial](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/simulate-mouse-events-in-python/#:%7E:text=Using%20pynput%20we%20are%20able,scroll%20and%20move%20the%20mouse.)